# Meaning of the product of two dependent random variables: $Z := XY$

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

This is the whole assignment text, for context:

*note on the notation: H is the entropy, I is the mutual information*

---

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space with $A,B \in \mathcal{A}, A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $P(A) = P(B) = \frac{1}{4}$. Let $X,Y : \Omega \rightarrow \{0,1,-1\}$ be random variables defined by
>
> $\begin{gather*}X(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in A \\ -1 & \omega \in B \\ 0 & else \end{cases} \end{gather*}$ and $\begin{gather*}Y(\omega) = \begin{cases} -1 & \omega \in A \\ 1 & \omega \in B \\ 0 & else \end{cases} \end{gather*}$
>
> - (a) Why are $X$ and $Y$ not independent ?
> - (b) Show that $H(X)=H(Y)=H(X,Y)=I(X;Y)=\frac{3}{2}$ and $H(X|Y)=H(Y|X) = 0$.
> - (c) Let $Z := XY$. Show that $H(Z) < H(X,Y) = H(X,Y,Z)$ and $H(Z|X)=0$ but $H(X|Z)>0$.
> - (d) Calculate $H(X|Z)$ and show that $H(X|Z)=I(X;Y|Z)$.

---

I need help answering (c). For (a) and (b) I wrote down the joint probability of $X$ and $Y$ in a table:

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline P(X=x,Y=y) & -1 & 0 & 1  \\\hline
  -1  & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\\hline
  0  & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\\hline
  1  & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\\hline
\end{array}
$

With this I can easily calculate all things asked in (a) and (b), but I do not understand the new random variable $Z:=XY$ and its meaning with respect to $X$ and $Y$. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Can't  things be simplified by just noting that $Y=-X$ (and e.g. consequently $Z=-X^2=-Y^2$). Where do $H$ and $I$ stand for? I am not familiar with that notation.

Comment: I have edited the question: H is the entropy, I is the mutual information.
Yes, it could be simplified by noting $Y = -X$ but I still have problems understanding what the product of two random variables actually means and how to use it in the context of question (c).

Comment: @Marco The notation $Z=XY$ is a shorthand for $Z(\omega)=X(\omega) Y(\omega), \omega \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @Marco Apologies, the above should be $\omega \in \Omega$

Comment: @Stelios thank you, your notation actually gave me a better idea how to solve this problem. Am I right in thinking that $Z=XY$ is a new random variable which takes on value $-1$ for $\omega \in (A \cup B)$ and the value $0$ else ?

Comment: @Marco That is correct and follows directly from what I remarked in my former comment: $Z=-X^2$.